# Nodejs Amazon Upload using Knox crashing at Assertion Error

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, upload, multipart, knox-amazon-s3-client

I'm using the knox amazon uploader as a "proxy" to upload a sliced file from Javascript.
But the thing that've noticing is that sometimes ( sadly sometimes so I cannot identify the error exactly) when the `response.statusCode` isn't 200 the nodeJS crashes at an exception:

> assert.js:93 throw new assert.AssertionError({
>
> AssertionError: true == false at IncomingMessage.
>   (http.js:1341:9) at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:61:17) at
>   HTTPParser.onMessageComplete (http.js:133:23) at Socket.ondata
>   (http.js:1231:22) at Socket._onReadable (net.js:683:27) at
>   IOWatcher.onReadable [as callback] (net.js:177:10)

**Does anyone knows why this happens? Is there a way to catch that exception avoiding the server to crash?**

Here's some code if it helps:

```
var request = client.request('PUT', '/' + params.fileName + '?partNumber=' +       params.partNumber + '&uploadId=' + params.uploadId, {
    'Content-Length': req.headers['content-length']
});

req.on('data', function(data){
    request.write(data, 'binary');
});
request.on('response', function(response) {
    if (response.statusCode== 200) { 
        console.log('Part '+ params.partNumber + ' inserted with etag: '+    response.headers.etag);
}
}).end();
```

Comment: Before the actual error it gives me this response:
    { Code: 'RequestTimeout',
    Message: 'Your socket connection to the server was not read from     or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be     closed.',
    RequestId: '97007DD8BAD530BB',
    HostId:   'Bl9b9ggKKdnF0bBief0i+1cNAT9eIQhObe2nMFYUqOktN3HlZ9lzs1izwAQxg50Y' }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be a bug in node.js < v0.5 where `Socket.destroySoon()` does not close the socket right away.

https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/1892

Comment: Just saw your response, sorry for being a little late =p. Upgrading the nodeJS to the current stable version 0.6.7 seems to solve the problem. Thanks!